# Extracting a texture in watchOS 3

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, watchkit, xcode8, ios10

I am using the following code in iOS 10.0 in my GameScene.swift

```
    //Shape storage
    let playerShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10 )
```

...Color setup etc

```
    //Get the texture from shape node
    let playerTexture = view?.texture(from: playerShape)
```

The same code doesn't work in watchOS 3.0
Xcode 8.0 beta 2 complaints about the view:

`Use of unresolved identifier 'view'`

Does anyone know whats the equivalent of view in watchOS?

Thank you.

Comment: what are you using,  I have never seen view?.texture(from:SKNode)  I have only seen view?.textureFromNode(SKNode)

Comment: WKInterfaceSKScene is what you use for watchOS,  skview does not exist

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfaceskscene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for the comments.
- view?.texture(from:SKNode) could be because of Swift 3
- I am doing this inside 
'class GameScene: SKScene'
which doesn't allow me to define it as a WKInterfaceSKScene as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above there are no views in Apple Watch's Sprite Kit.
So that is why you are unable to use view in your code.

Just use SKSpriteNode instead and do something like this if you want the texture for something else.

E.g. here I want to use my circleOriginal texture on circle 2

```
  let circleOriginal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
  let circleTexture = circleOriginal.texture

  let circle2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: circleTexture)
```

If you want an amazing overview of Apple Watch Game Tech check out Apple's WWDC lecture on it (The slides below are from there). This explains a lot and provides great code examples.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/612/

Here are the key differences.

**Here's Apple's Scene Graph for non-watchOS**

[image]

**Here's Apple's Scene Graph corresponding Scene Graph for watchOS**

[image]

**Here are the recommended alternatives for watchOS's SpriteKit / SceneKit**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @corey-f for the answer!